# Jspdf special element handler for all elements beginning with "#ember"

Tags: javascript, regex, ember.js, jspdf

I am using the jspdf library to generate a PDF from an html page with a lot of javascript. The javascript framework I am using is Ember, so there are a lot of id="ember234" tags inserted everywhere, with the digits on the end being generated randomly.

Jspdf cannot handle these elements, so I'll need to insert them in the elementHandlers hash below.  Is there a way to add any element that starts with the substring "ember" to this hash?  Many thanks for your help

```
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.fromHTML($('.report-management-interface').html(), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': {}
  });
  doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute just specifies a unique identifier for elements in the dom.  It's extremely common and doubtfully the reason the pdf isn't working.  They are generated using an incrementing counter, Ember.guidFor.  They are on every type of element/method/object/array etc.  That being said the guid itself is worthless for distinguishing how to handle an element differently.

Personally I would think the metamorph tags would be more likely to cause issues.